# Extract information from string and save it to database

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, jquery-ui

I have multiple columns `<ul>` which are sortable by jQuery UI. To save positions of `<li>` inside those `<ul>` I need to serialize data.

```
$(function() {
 $("ul.sortable").sortable({
    connectWith: '.sortable',
    update: function(event, ui) {
   /* var position = $('.sortable').sortable('serialize', {
            key: 'menu',
            connected: true
        });*/
    $('div').empty().html( $('.sortable').serial() );
    }
  });
});


(function($) {
$.fn.serial = function() {
 var array = [];
 var $elem = $(this); 
    $elem.each(function(i) {
      var menu = this.id;
        $('li', this).each(function(e) {
                array.push( menu + '['+e+']=' + this.id  );
        });
    });
    return array.join('&');      
    }

})(jQuery);
```

This is how I serialize data (found this example on another thread)

I need id of column and id of row so I can save them to database.

Output looks like this: menu1[0]=id_2&menu1[1]=id_1&menu2[0]=id_3&menu2[1]=id_4&menu3[0]=id_5&menu3[1]=id_6

So 'menu1, menu2 ...' are columns ids and id_1, id_2 are row ids. And of course I need to know where to put `<li>` and I do that by extracting number between [].

So my question is how to extract all relevant information which I mentioned so I can send those information to database.

Comment: You have all the relevant info, but you're smushing it all into a hard-to-parse string.  How do you want to save it to the database?  Do you have a schema in mind?  Once it's in the database, how do you want to be able to use it?

Comment: I plan to use this query: "update list set position = 'some_position' where columnId = 'some_column_id' and itemId = 'some_item_id'.
So 'position' is information in []
'columnId' is information before []
'itemId' is information after =

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It'd be easier to work with if you serialize to something like this; the position is just the index within the items array.

```
[ 
  { "column" : "menu1", "items" : [ "id_2", "id_1" ] },
  { "column" : "menu2", "items" : [ "id_3", "id_4" ] },
  { "column" : "menu3", "items" : [ "id_5", "id_6" ] }
]
```

You can create that like this:

```
(function($) {
    $.fn.serial = function() {
        var menus = [];
        var $elem = $(this); 
        $elem.each(function(i) {
            var menu = this.id;
            var items = [];
            $('li', this).each(function(e) {
                items.push( this.id  );
            });
            menus.push({ "column" : menu, "items": items });
        });
        return menus;
    }
})(jQuery);
```

and iterate through it like this:

```
for (var m = 0; m < menus.length; m++) {
    var menu = menus[m];
    var column = menu["column"];
    var items = menu["items"];
    for (var i = 0; i < items.length; i++) {
        update(i, column, items[i])
    }
}
```